# Expectation and variance of the number of elements of a random non-empty set selected from a finite power set

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions, alternative-proof, binomial-distribution

> Let $S$ denote a finite set of cardinality $|S| = N$. Select randomly a non-empty subset of $S$. Let $X$ indicate the number of items belonging to this subset.
>
> (a) Describe the probability mass function of $X$ and compute $\textbf{E}(X)$ and $\textbf{Var}(X)$.
>
> (b) Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\textbf{E}(X)}{N} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\textbf{V}(X)}{N} = \frac{1}{4}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) In the first place, we first notice there are $C(N,x)$ subsets which has $x$ elements, where $1\leq x\leq N$. Therefore we conclude that
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{2^{N} - 1}{N\choose x}
\end{align*}

From then on we are able to determine $\textbf{E}(X)$ and $\textbf{Var}(X)$. Precisely speaking, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=1}^{N}{N\choose x}x & = \sum_{x=1}^{N}\frac{N!}{(x-1)!(N-x)!} = \sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\frac{N!}{x!(N-x-1)!}\\
& = N\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\frac{(N-1)!}{x!(N-x-1)!} = N\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}{N-1\choose x} = N2^{N-1}
\end{align*}

according to the binomial theorem. From whence we conclude that
$$\textbf{E}(X) = \frac{N2^{N-1}}{2^{N}-1}$$

Further, we do also have the following identity

\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=1}^{N}{N\choose x}x^{2} & = \sum_{x=1}^{N}\left[\frac{N!}{(x-1)!(N-x)!}\right]x = \sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\left[\frac{N!}{x!(N-x-1)!}\right](x+1)\\
& = \sum_{x=1}^{N-1}\frac{N!}{(x-1)!(N-x-1)!} + \sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\frac{N!}{x!(N-x-1)!}\\
& = N(N-1)\sum_{x=0}^{N-2}\frac{(N-2)!}{x!(N-x-2)!} + N\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\frac{(N-1)!}{x!(N-x-1)!}\\
& = N(N-1)\sum_{x=0}^{N-2}{N\choose x} + N\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}{N-1\choose x} = N(N-1)2^{N-2} + N2^{N-1}
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$\textbf{E}(X^{2}) = \frac{N(N-1)2^{N-2} + N2^{N-1}}{2^{N}-1}$$

Finally, we have the variance:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\textbf{Var}(X)}{N} & = \frac{\textbf{E}(X^{2}) - \textbf{E}(X)^{2}}{N}
\end{align*}

(b) As requested, we obtain the desired result
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\textbf{E}(X)}{N} = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{N-1}}{2^{N}-1} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

However, the same does not apply to the variance when I make use of the results obtained. Am I committing some conceptual mistake? I would be equally grateful if someone provided me a quicker or smarter way to tackle this problem.

**EDIT**

I edited my answer as suggested by Did. Nonetheless, I am still thinking there is something wrong with my solution. Could someone double-check my calculations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first mistake (I did not look further) is when you write $$\sum_{x=1}^{N-1}\frac{N!}{(x-1)!(N-x-1)!} = \sum_{x=0}^{N-2}\frac{N!}{x!(N-x)!}$$ Yes one should replace $x$ by $x-1$ but then $(N-x-1)!$ becomes $(N-x-2)!$, not $(N-x)!$.

Comment: For an alternative proof, use the fact that $X$ equals in distribution $Y$ conditioned on $Y\ne0$, where $Y$ is binomial $(N,\frac12)$. Thus, $$E(X)=E(Y\mid Y\ne0)=\frac{E(Y)}{1-p}\qquad E(X^2)=E(Y^2\mid Y\ne0)=\frac{E(Y^2)}{1-p}$$ where $$p=P(Y=0)=2^{-N}$$ and $E(Y)$ and $E(Y^2)$ should be in your bag of known facts. Likewise, for every positive $k$, $$E(X^k)=\frac{E(Y^k)}{1-p}$$

Comment: Did, can you add your comment as an answer so I can better understand it and vote it up?

Comment: "However, the same does not apply to the variance when I make use of the results obtained" Again, we cannot know what and if you did something wrong since you neither show what you did nor what you got for the variance. The partial computations you do show indeed lead to $\mathrm{Var}(X_N)\sim N/4$.

Answer (score -2):

Seem probably simpler if you look at it this way: Say $S$ has $n$ elements. If  $Y$ is the number of elements of a randomly selected element of the power set, including the empty set as a possibility, then $Y$ has the same distribution as $X_1+\dots+X_n$, where the $X_j$ are iid with $P(X_1=0)=P(X_1=1)=1/2$.

Comment: Ok, what's the problem with that? The OP _said_ " I would be equally grateful if someone provided me a quicker or smarter way to tackle this problem."

Comment: Well, I cannot speak for others but the fact is that you do not tackle the problem asked since your Y is not distributed like the X in the question.